# Connecting two coordinates with Polyline? Cartodb?

Tags: carto, coordinates, csv, mapbox

I have some trip data and I want to draw a line between the start and end coordinates.

I have two layers in CartoDB - one contains the start coordinates (with trip_id & cartodb_id). The other contains the corresponding end coordinates (with trip_id & cartodb_id).

As I'm new to CartoDB/SQL in general, how can I join these the two coordinates for the same trip?

I found this code somewhere but it hasn't been working for me thus far:

```
SELECT 
  ST_MakeLine(
    the_geom_webmercator, 
    (SELECT 
      the_geom_webmercator
    FROM 
      hubway_july2012_end   
    WHERE trip_id = cartodb_id LIMIT 1
    )
  ) AS the_geom_webmercator 
  FROM 
  hubway_july2012_start
    AS c
```

(I've edited it a little bit, but I'm not sure if what I have done is right).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] as an introduction to our focussed Q&A format.  You have mentioned CartoDB in your title so I suggest that you explore that as your first candidate rather than asking for [softwarerecs.se] here on a site that starts from the premise that you are already using or well into researching a particular software.  Previous questions have been asked here that are [tagged CartoDB and CSV](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartodb+csv) - they could be worth reviewing for ideas of how they can interact.

Comment: Does it appear to be working. If not, what is wrong?

Comment: No it's not for some reason! If I put this code into the SQL box for the start coordinates layer, all the points on that layer just disappear.

Comment: And vice versa if I do the same for the end coordinates layer

Answer (score 1):

For what you say I'm assuming you can link start and end points by their trip_id. If that's the case (and each trip only has one point stored in table A and one in table B) then your sql only needs to do the relation right (now you are using cartodb_id vs trip_id, which I don't think is correct).

I'd maybe do something like this:

```
WITH coords AS
 (SELECT 
 a.the_geom_webmercator as coord_a, 
 b.the_geom_webmercator AS coord_b 
 FROM hubway_july2012_start a JOIN hubway_july2012_end b on a.trip_id=b.trip_id )

SELECT ST_MakeLine(coord_a, coord_b) AS the_geom_webmercator FROM coords
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. 

This might be a stupid question but would I put that in the SQL box for the start or end layer? (right now I have two layers - one is for the start coordinates and the other is for the end coordinates)

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter. Whatever you put in that box gets executed as SQL regardless of the currently selected table